# awk compare consecutive rows

Tags: awk, compare, rows

This is quite simple maybe, but I am stacked.Thanks for any help.
I have an input file with two two columns. In one column I have an ID and in the second a value associated to it.  I need an output where the first column will be the ID (no repetitions are allowed) and in the second column the average is printed. The ids are not always repeated, and if repeated it could only be consecutively and at a max repetition value of two.

Input

```
10;10
10;20
20;30
20;40
30;15
40;10
40;12
```

Desired output

```
10;15
20;35
30;15
40;11
```

Comment: Any number of questions on this site are similar enough to this that you should be able to figure it out from them.

Comment: I am sorry, I have checked some of them but still confused... any additonal help, please?

Answer (score 4):

This one-liner does it:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{a[$1]+=$2+0;b[$1]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]/b[x]}' file
```

Test with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
10;10
10;20
20;30
20;40
30;15
40;10
40;12

kent$  awk -F';' -v OFS=";" '{a[$1]+=$2+0;b[$1]++}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]/b[x]}' f
10;15
20;35
30;15
40;11
```

Comment: @fedorqui true, I had `OFS`, I removed because I have `printf` anyway, `OFS` makes the `printf` longer.. :-)

Comment: @fedorqui you are right.... !! I forgot `a/b` would be int..... urh... I update it

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if I really have other columns in the input file that I also want to print the average value? I thought it would be easy for me to add this to your script but I really do not know how... The actual input file has 80 columns acting as the second one I mentioned...

Comment: Nevermind! I learnt so much from you that I am happy to show back something, sometimes :D

Comment: Just mention that the output will be in "random" order, the fact it's the same order as the input above is pure co-incidence. Why are you adding zero to $2?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
($1 != prev) && (NR>1) { print prev, sum/cnt; sum=cnt=0 }
{ prev=$1; sum+=$2; cnt++ }
END { if (cnt) print prev, sum/cnt }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
10;15
20;35
30;15
40;11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if I really have other columns in the input file that I also want to print the average value? I thought it would be easy for me to add this to your script but I really do not know how... The actual input file has 80 columns acting as the second one I mentioned

Comment: Then you should really show those other columns in the sample input/output in your question. Whatever you want to do will be trivial but your comment could mean one of several things. And no - do not show 80 columns, 3 or 4 columns will work just fine.

Comment: @user3666956 some advice - in software solutions there is a world of difference between 1 item and 2 items, and between 2 items and 3 items. There's also a world of difference between consecutive and non-consecutive items. So if you are posting a question THINK about how you can show a minimal example that captures your problem but if the real problem involves 3 or more items then don't show an example with 1 item (or even 2 items) and hope the solution is the same as for 3 or more.

Comment: Sorry, it was a novice error...I will consider this for the future, and I guess I need to post a new question because you are not helping me within this one? Anyway, thanks for the advice and sorry again!

Comment: No-one is helping you with your new requirements simply because you haven't done what you were told you need to do for us to be able to help you - edit your question to show updated sample input/output that reflects those requirements. It's been so long now, though, that I doubt if anyone's looking at this question any more so at this point you may as well mark an answer accepted and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

(written live, I did not try it; assume GNU awk; assume sorted input)

```
awk -F';' '
    BEGIN {
        id=""
    }
    $1 != id {
        if (id != "") {
            printf("%s;%d\n", id, sum/n);
            n = sum = 0;
            id = str($1);
        }
        sum += $2;
        n++;
    }
    END {
        if (n > 0) printf("%s;%s\n", id, sum/n);
    }
'
```

Comment: There's nothing gawk-specific about it but running the above would produce a syntax error due to trying to use single quotes inside a single quote delimited script, and there's no function named `str()` in awk, and you don't need the spurious trailing semi-colons, and printf is a builtin, not a function, so the parens around the printf args are not doing what you probably think they are. Once al of that is fixed, it will also fail with a divide by zero error if ran on an empty file.

Comment: @EdMorton I can live with that. I wrote it directly, not tested, as warned. Note that the OP did not try anything before asking. I fixed the most obvious mistakes; didn't know about printf, I always use it that way and it just works.